# How to get dropdownlist variables

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a dropdownlist in my view which consists of true and false.
But I am storing one more value which I need to pass to controller.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DropDown, Model.DropDown, new {Id  = "DropDown,@Text="782});



$('#DropDown').change(function() {

    var y = $(this).val();
    alert(y);

});
```

Currently I have a jquery dropdownchange function to get true or false.

But how can I get this @text value in jquery function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+get+dropdown+text

Answer (score 0):

Try using `option:selected`

```
 var y = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
 alert(y);
```